# The meaning of となった in this context

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

the meaning of となった in this context is not entirely clear for me. Help, onegai.

> 世界同時株安の**発端となった**ニューヨーク株式市場は、11日も売り注文が続き、ダウ平均株価は一時、前日に比べて700ドル近く値下がりしました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note the translation of the word in question:

- X となる = "to become X"

Furthermore, note that putting a verb before a noun is a way to describe the noun. For example:

- {話す/話した}人 = "A person who (will) talks/talked"
- "田中さんが食べたステーキ" = "The steak that Mr. Tanaka ate."

So basically, the whole first part of the phrase (up to and including となった) are used to describe the noun after it: "ニューヨーク株式市場"

> **世界同時株安の発端となった**ニューヨーク株式市場は ...
>
> The New York stock market **which became the origin of a worldwide simultaneous period of low stock prices** ...